# JavaFX saving properties to DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, javafx, properties

I am editing my original question, since i changed a lot, and i still have same problem :

so my Model class is :

```
package beans;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private IntegerProperty id;
    private StringProperty firstName;
    private StringProperty lastName;
    private IntegerProperty age;
    private StringProperty address;

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName, int age, String address) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
    }

    public IntegerProperty IdProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty FirstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty LastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "age")
    public int getAge() {
        return age.get();
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
    }

    public IntegerProperty AgeProperty() {
        return age;
    }

    @Column(name = "address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address.get();
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
    }

    public StringProperty AddressProperty() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", age=" + age + ", address=" + address + '}';
    }


}
```

and my method for saving is :

```
@FXML
private void savePerson() {
    Person p = new Person();

    p.setFirstName(firstnameF.getText());
    p.setLastName(lastnameF.getText());
    p.setAge(Integer.parseInt(ageF.getText()));
    p.setAddress(addressF.getText());
    System.out.println(p);
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();


    try (Session session = sf.openSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(p);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        clearFields();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

finally error i get is :

```
  Person{id=IntegerProperty [value: 1], firstName=StringProperty [value:    a], lastName=StringProperty [value: at], age=IntegerProperty [value: 2], address=StringProperty [value: a]}
    Jan 25, 2017 7:59:11 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.7.Final}
    Jan 25, 2017 7:59:11 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Jan 25, 2017 7:59:11 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jan 25, 2017 7:59:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 25, 2017 7:59:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JavafxHibernateTest]
Jan 25, 2017 7:59:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Jan 25, 2017 7:59:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 25, 2017 7:59:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 50 (min=1)
Wed Jan 25 19:59:12 CET 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Jan 25, 2017 7:59:12 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jan 25, 2017 7:59:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JavafxHibernateTest]
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at beans.UiController.savePerson(UiController.java:43)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of beans.Person.id
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:41)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at beans.Person.getId(Person.java:42)
    ... 80 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 31 seconds)
```

I am really not sure what seems to be the problem, my model works fine if its primitive types instead properties type, so i assume model is fine, i changed annotation system and problem persists, i cleaned my database, but i always get an error.

Comment: Perhaps sharing the error you are getting would help solve the problem

Comment: i edited orginal to include error

Comment: Annotate the `get` methods, not the properties themselves  (i.e. `getAge`, not `age` or `ageProperty()`). Also fix your method names, which do not follow the conventions: `getFirstName()` not `getfirstName()`, `setLastName()` not `setlastName()` etc etc. See http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa.html and http://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2014/05/09/one-bean-to-bind-them-all/

Comment: A) Don't add something like [SOLVED] to the question title. Accept an answer instead. B) Do not add an answer to the question. You can answer your own question, if there is no answer providing this solution. BTW: Constructor chaining would also be an option: `public Person() {
this(0, null, null, 0, null);}` Also replacing a property is a bad idea. You can initialize properties lazily, but this should be done in the property method and the default value should be returned from the getter method in case the property is not initialized...

Comment: @fabian  I changed originall post and added answer to my question, sorry for that.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` annotation to your class. Now Hibernate will look for columns in getter methods. Then add `@Column(name = "id")` annotations to your getters.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private IntegerProperty id;
    private StringProperty firstName;
    private StringProperty lastName;
    private IntegerProperty age;
    private StringProperty address;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName, int age, String address) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "age")
    public int getAge() {
        return age.get();
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
    }

    public IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
        return age;
    }

    @Column(name = "address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address.get();
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
    }

    public StringProperty addressProperty() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you annotate the `get` methods (instead of the fields), Hibernate will infer `AccessType.PROPERTY` - though I completely agree that it is good practice to annotate it explicitly.

Comment: It does not work i made my class look exactly like the one you linked, and i still cant persist, it complains about invocation target and nullPointer exception at Person.getId

Comment: You use default constructor for creating `Person` object, but in that constructor you don't inintalize any of your properties, that is why you get `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by chaning deleting both constructors and making constructor look like this :

```
public Person() {
this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
}
```

after that everything worked properly

i also changed all setters to from

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName.set(firstName);
}
```

but this is not related to original problem.